# Simple Controller not working as expected

Tags: java, html, spring

I have a menu that I use in all pages. The problem is that when I am on a page with multiple dir example : `localhost:8080/user/edit` when I click to go to the home page instead of `localhost:8080/dashboard`, I get `localhost:8080/user/dasboard`

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("dasboard")
public ModelAndView editTestCase(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //code
}

@RequestMapping("user/edit")
public ModelAndView editTestCase(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //code
}
```

Menu:

```
 <li class="nav-item" id="dashboard">
     <a class="nav-link" href="dashboard">
         <img src="../resources/img/icons/dashboard-icon.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
         <span class="menu-title">Dashboard</span>
     </a>
 </li>
```

Comment: Try  <a class="nav-link" href="/dashboard">

Comment: i think that solved. i didnt put the / because i got a warning

Comment: I don't see any {context} in your href. This will simply look for the controller in your current directory. Second thing. I am not sure if you are actually specifying the @Path for your resource which actually contains these methods